# Thread-local instance-local variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I would like a thread-local (in the context of a Rails app, per request), instance local var, by way of example imagine I have instance of an object which is globally accessible.

```
module Event
  def self.bus
    @bus ||= Bus.new
  end
end
```

The `bus` object can have metadata set per request:

```
class Bus
  def with_metadata(metadata, &block)
    @metadata = metadata
    block.call
  end

  # ...
end
```

The problem is that in a threaded environment, like a Rails application on Puma, `@metadata` is shared globally between the different threads (i.e. requests), so if the metadata contains an IP address, for example, it will be incorrect for only some requests.

We could use `Thread.current` which is thread local:

```
class Bus
  def with_metadata(metadata, &block)
    Thread.current["with_metadata"] = metadata
    block.call
  ensure
    Thread.current["with_metadata"] = nil
  end

  # ...
end
```

However this introduces a problem, if another instance of the bus object is initialized in the same thread, i.e. `Event.bus` and `Bus.new`, they incorrectly share the "with_metadata" state.

My thought was to include the `object_id` in the key:

```
class Bus
  def with_metadata(metadata, &block)
    Thread.current["#{object_id}_with_metadata"] = metadata
    block.call
  ensure
    Thread.current["#{object_id}_with_metadata"] = nil
  end

  # ...
end
```

Does this sound reasonable, is there an idiomatic way of having a thread-local, instance-local var? I do not want a dependency on Rails, or any other library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails depends on the [concurrent-ruby](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby) gem which brings you a lot of tools to deal with multi-threaded and concurrent environments.

Specifically, you can use the [`Concurrent::ThreadLocalVar`](https://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/1.1.10/Concurrent/ThreadLocalVar.html) class here:

```
class Bus
  def initialize
    @metadata = Concurrent::ThreadLocalVar.new
  end

  def metadata
    @metadata.value
  end

  def with_metadata(metadata, &block)
    @metadata.value = metadata
    yield
  ensure
    @metadata.value = nil
  end

  # ...
end
```

Please refer to the documentation linked above for more usage examples.

Comment: Nice, I will look in to this.